# How do we get "four" when it doesn't follow Grimm's law?

Tags: etymology, sound-change

I understand how Grimm's law has resulted in pairs such as duo / two, tri / three, penta / five. But how do we get "four"? I looked it up in the dictionary and the IE root is 
‌‌kwetwer-  Why doesn't our number four start with /h/ ?

Comment: What about the second _f_ in the OE _fif_ '5' < PG _*fimfe_ < PIE _*penkwe-_? OE _f_ < PIE _*kw_.

Comment: Sanskrit derived it as chatwaar and further Hindi as chaar Latin derived it as Quad.

Answer (score 7):

There is no straightforward explanation for Germanic, but influence from "5" is suspected. There is an article (Patrick Stiles, 1986, NOWELE 8: 3-25) which addresses this but it's not available to me.

Comment: Slavic *neviat* (from PIE *newn*) > *deviat* "9" due to the following *desiat* "10" (from PIE *dekmt*). Latin *sex* "6" instead of *suex* due to the following *septem*. There are many more examples like this. So what you cite is more than likely.

Answer (score 1):

Frederik Kortlandt in   Labials, velars and labiovelars in Germanic. North-Western European Language Evolution 30 (1997), 45-50. addresses how in many cases PIE *kw > p > Germanic f in words such as 'wolf', 'eleven', 'twelve', 'leave', 'liver' and a similar change (gw > b > p) in 'warp'. However he still thinks 'four' gains it's first consonant from similarity to 'five'